# Enumerating properties in a type in C++

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

I'm working on a Wordclock with an Arduino so we're in C++. I want to save the corresponding Pixels and length of the words in a type so I can call a function that takes the Word to display as a property.

So here is what I came up with:

```
(Pseudocode)
type WORD
    property1 = pixelPosition (integer)
    property2 = wordLength (also integer)
```

I also would like to implement all the values in a compact form like in a enum like this:

```
word1= (123, 3);
```

Instead of this:

```
word1.pixelPos = 123;
word1.length = 3;
```

Unfortunately I didnt find a way to set two values in an enum. Is there a way I can create a custom type and set it to be the kind of type I want to enum?

Comment: Are you looking for classes? You can store multiple named members of different types, and aggregate-initialize an instance of one with a similar syntax to what you have (only with braces instead of parentheses).

Comment: Depending on how `WORD` is defined, `word1 = {123, 3};` may work out of the box, no special tricks necessary. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3f4ea7bMc)

Comment: I'm getting an Error "error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'wort' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')" with your Solution, Igor